# How can scrapy export items to separate csv files per item

Tags: csv, scrapy, exporter

I am scraping a soccer site and the spider (a single spider) gets several kinds of items from the site's pages: Team, Match, Club etc.
I am trying to use the CSVItemExporter to store these items in separate csv files,
teams.csv, matches.csv, clubs.csv etc.

I am not sure what is the right way to do this.
The only way I have thought so far is to create my own custom pipeline like in the example 
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/exporters.html  and there open all needed csv files in the spider_opened method, ie create a csv exporter for each csv file and in the process_item put code to figure out what kind of item is the "item" parameter and then send it to the corresponding exporter object.

Anyway I haven't found any examples of handling multiple csv files (per item type) in scrapy so I am worrying that I am using it in a way that is not meant to be used. (this is my first experience with Scrapy).

diomedes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You approach seems fine to me. Piplines are a great feature of Scrapy and are IMO build for something like your approach.

You could create multiple items (e.g. SoccerItem, MatchItem) and in your `MultiCSVItemPipeline` just delegate each item to its own CSV class by checking the item class.

Comment: Ok, after writing the MultiCSVItemPipeline I feel better :-). I check as you suggested the item class to figure out where the item goes. I am giving a self answer to show the code for anyone that has the same question.

Comment: @Diomedes - Could you please share you code for items.py, spider code, and also settings.py. It will be very helpful. As i am getting csv file as empty using the below same code. Scrapy version for me is 1.8.0. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

I am posting here the code I used to produce a `MultiCSVItemPipeline` based on the answer of  drcolossos above.

This pipeline assumes that all the Item classes follow the convention *Item (e.g. TeamItem, EventItem) and creates team.csv, event.csv files and sends all records to the appropriate csv files.

```py
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher


def item_type(item):
    return type(item).__name__.replace('Item','').lower()  # TeamItem => team

class MultiCSVItemPipeline(object):
    SaveTypes = ['team','club','event', 'match']
    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.files = dict([ (name, open(CSVDir+name+'.csv','w+b')) for name in self.SaveTypes ])
        self.exporters = dict([ (name,CsvItemExporter(self.files[name])) for name in self.SaveTypes])
        [e.start_exporting() for e in self.exporters.values()]

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        [e.finish_exporting() for e in self.exporters.values()]
        [f.close() for f in self.files.values()]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        what = item_type(item)
        if what in set(self.SaveTypes):
            self.exporters[what].export_item(item)
        return item
```

Comment: Can you please include the code where you import some modules?

Comment: What is dispatcher used for?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the answer. It seems do not work in the latest version (2.21).

I have included my code for your reference:

```py
class MultiCSVItemPipeline(object):
    SaveTypes = ['CentalineTransactionsItem','CentalineTransactionsDetailItem','CentalineBuildingInfo']

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.files = dict([ (name, open(name+'.csv','w+b')) for name in self.SaveTypes ])
        self.exporters = dict([ (name,CsvItemExporter(self.files[name])) for name in self.SaveTypes])
        [e.start_exporting() for e in self.exporters.values()]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        [e.finish_exporting() for e in self.exporters.values()]
        [f.close() for f in self.files.values()]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        what = type(item).__name__
        if what in set(self.SaveTypes):
            self.exporters[what].export_item(item)
        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Scrapy = "^2.5.0" and had to do a couple of modifications so it works. I've also made the `SaveTypes` (now `defined_items`) dynamic to all Items in the items file.

```py
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
from YOUR_PROJECT import items


def item_type(item):
    return type(item).__name__


class MultiCSVItemPipeline(object):
    defined_items = [name for name, _ in items.__dict__.items() if "Item" in name]

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.files = dict(
            [
                (name, open("FOLDER_TO_SAVE/" + name + ".csv", "w+b"))
                for name in self.defined_items
            ]
        )
        self.exporters = dict(
            [(name, CsvItemExporter(self.files[name])) for name in self.defined_items]
        )
        [e.start_exporting() for e in self.exporters.values()]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        [e.finish_exporting() for e in self.exporters.values()]
        [f.close() for f in self.files.values()]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item_name = item_type(item)
        if item_name in set(self.defined_items):
            self.exporters[item_name].export_item(item)
        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to leverage scrapy's [Item Pipline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) and Exporters to output a separate csv per Item class type scraped. The logic closely resembles [this example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#using-item-exporters).

```
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

class cvs_per_itemtype_Pipeline:

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.itemType_to_exporterAndCsvFile = {}     

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        itemType = type(item).__name__ #item class name as str
        if itemType not in self.itemType_to_exporterAndCsvFile:
            csvFile = open(f'{itemType}.csv', 'wb')
            exporter = CsvItemExporter(csvFile)
            exporter.start_exporting()
            self.itemType_to_exporterAndCsvFile[itemType] = (exporter, csvFile)
        exporter = self.itemType_to_exporterAndCsvFile[itemType][0]
        exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        for exporter, csvFile in self.itemType_to_exporterAndCsvFile.values():
            exporter.finish_exporting()
            csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now an easy method to achieve this. We can configure feed exports in `settings.py` file as shown below -

```
FEED = {
    'team.csv': {
        'format': 'csv',
        'encoding': 'utf8',
        'store_empty': False,
        'item_classes': [MyItemClass1, 'myproject.items.TeamItem'],
        'fields': None,
        'indent': 4,
        'item_export_kwargs': {
           'export_empty_fields': True,
        },
    },
{
    'club.csv': {
        'format': 'csv',
        'encoding': 'utf8',
        'store_empty': False,
        'item_classes': ['myproject.items.ClubItem'],
        'fields': None,
        'indent': 4,
        'item_export_kwargs': {
           'export_empty_fields': True,
        },
    },
```

This will generate two different `.csv` files and redirect the corresponding items as per `item_classes` key above.

The docs are not much clear but here is the link from where I infered this - [Feed Exports](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feeds)