# scrapy: read list of urls from file and export scraped values in separate csv as url names

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, export-to-csv

I am reading a list of urls from a links.csv file as follows:

```
/node/2553181
/node/2553439
/node/2552825
```

I am opening the url and scraping using code:

```
def start_requests(self):
        f = open('./links.csv','r').readlines()
        for url in f:
            url = 'https://example.com'+url.strip()
            yield scrapy.Request(url)
def parse_page(self, response):
        item = posts()
        item["poston"]=response.xpath("//h1[@id='page-subtitle']/text()").extract()
        item["postby"]=response.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'node-')]/div[1]/a/@href").extract()
        myposts=[]
        myposts.append(item)
        return myposts
```

I am able to export the content in single result.csv using:

```
scrapy crawl postspider -t csv -o result.csv
```

But i'd like to save the results in a separate file for each item as:

```
2553181.csv
2553439.csv
2552825.csv
```

The solution provided [How can scrapy export items to separate csv files per item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230332/how-can-scrapy-export-items-to-separate-csv-files-per-item) don't address my problem, as i need to export in different csv files as per the input url file names