# How can I get this Spider to export a JSON file for each Items List?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, scrapy

In my following file `Reddit.py`, it has this Spider:

```
import scrapy

class RedditSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Reddit'
    allowed_domains = ['reddit.com']
    start_urls = ['https://old.reddit.com']

    def parse(self, response):

        for link in response.css('li.first a.comments::attr(href)').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_topics)



    def parse_topics(self, response):
        topics = {}
        topics["title"] = response.css('a.title::text').extract_first()
        topics["author"] = response.css('p.tagline a.author::text').extract_first()

        if response.css('div.score.likes::attr(title)').extract_first() is not None:
            topics["score"] = response.css('div.score.likes::attr(title)').extract_first()
        else:
            topics["score"] = "0"

        if int(topics["score"]) > 10000:
            author_url = response.css('p.tagline a.author::attr(href)').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(author_url), callback=self.parse_user, meta={'topics': topics})
        else:
            yield topics

    def parse_user(self, response):
        topics = response.meta.get('topics')

        users = {}
        users["name"] = topics["author"]
        users["karma"] = response.css('span.karma::text').extract_first()

        yield users
        yield topics
```

What it does that it gets all the URLs from the main page of `old.reddit`, Then scrape each URL's **title**, **author** and **score**.

What I've added to it is a second part, Where it checks if the **score** is higher than **10000**, If it is, Then the Spider goes to the **user**'s page and scrape his **karma** from it.

I do understand that I can scrape the **karma** from the **topic**'s page, But I would like to do it this way, Since there is other part of the **user**'s page I scrape That doesn't exist in the **topic**'s page.

What I want to do is to export the `topics` list which contains `title, author, score` into a `JSON` file named `topics.json`, Then if the **topic**'s score is higher than **10000** to export the `users` list which contains `name, karma` into a `JSON` file named `users.json`.

I only know how to use the `command-line` of

```
scrapy runspider Reddit.py -o Reddit.json
```

Which exports all the lists into a single `JSON` file named `Reddit` but in a bad structure like this

```
[
  {"name": "Username", "karma": "00000"},
  {"title": "ExampleTitle1", "author": "Username", "score": "11000"},
  {"name": "Username2", "karma": "00000"},
  {"title": "ExampleTitle2", "author": "Username2", "score": "12000"},
  {"name": "Username3", "karma": "00000"},
  {"title": "ExampleTitle3", "author": "Username3", "score": "13000"},
  {"title": "ExampleTitle4", "author": "Username4", "score": "9000"},
  ....
]
```

---

I have no-knowledge at all about **Scrapy**'s `Item Pipeline` nor `Item Exporters` & `Feed Exporters` on how to implement them on my Spider, or how to use them overall, Tried to understand it from the Documentation, But it doesn't seem I get how to use it in my Spider.

---

The final result I want is two files:

***topics.json***

```
[
 {"title": "ExampleTitle1", "author": "Username", "score": "11000"},
 {"title": "ExampleTitle2", "author": "Username2", "score": "12000"},
 {"title": "ExampleTitle3", "author": "Username3", "score": "13000"},
 {"title": "ExampleTitle4", "author": "Username4", "score": "9000"},
 ....
]
```

***users.json***

```
[
  {"name": "Username", "karma": "00000"},
  {"name": "Username2", "karma": "00000"},
  {"name": "Username3", "karma": "00000"},
  ....
]
```

while getting rid of duplicates in the list.

Comment: What's the desired output format? Also, I understand that you want to output (yield) at most one item per topic found.

Comment: @Apalala I actually want to make each `yield` output to has its own `JSON` file, instead of all in a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying approach from below SO thread

[Export scrapy items to different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083638/export-scrapy-items-to-different-files/50133981#50133981)

I created a sample scraper

```
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {"type": "unknown item"}
        yield {"title": "ExampleTitle1", "author": "Username", "score": "11000"}
        yield {"name": "Username", "karma": "00000"}
        yield {"name": "Username2", "karma": "00000"}
        yield {"someothertype": "unknown item"}

        yield {"title": "ExampleTitle2", "author": "Username2", "score": "12000"}
        yield {"title": "ExampleTitle3", "author": "Username3", "score": "13000"}
        yield {"title": "ExampleTitle4", "author": "Username4", "score": "9000"}
        yield {"name": "Username3", "karma": "00000"}
```

And then in `exporters.py`

```
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter
from scrapy.extensions.feedexport import FileFeedStorage


class JsonMultiFileItemExporter(JsonItemExporter):
    types = ["topics", "users"]

    def __init__(self, file, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(file, **kwargs)
        self.files = {}
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        for itemtype in self.types:
            storage = FileFeedStorage(itemtype + ".json")
            file = storage.open(None)
            self.files[itemtype] = JsonItemExporter(file, **self.kwargs)

    def start_exporting(self):
        super().start_exporting()
        for exporters in self.files.values():
            exporters.start_exporting()

    def finish_exporting(self):
        super().finish_exporting()
        for exporters in self.files.values():
            exporters.finish_exporting()
            exporters.file.close()

    def export_item(self, item):
        if "title" in item:
            itemtype = "topics"
        elif "karma" in item:
            itemtype = "users"
        else:
            itemtype = "self"

        if itemtype == "self" or itemtype not in self.files:
            super().export_item(item)
        else:
            self.files[itemtype].export_item(item)
```

Add below to the `settings.py`

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'json': 'testing.exporters.JsonMultiFileItemExporter',
}
```

Running the scraper I get 3 files generated

**example.json**

```
[
{"type": "unknown item"},
{"someothertype": "unknown item"}
]
```

**topics.json**

```
[
{"title": "ExampleTitle1", "author": "Username", "score": "11000"},
{"title": "ExampleTitle2", "author": "Username2", "score": "12000"},
{"title": "ExampleTitle3", "author": "Username3", "score": "13000"},
{"title": "ExampleTitle4", "author": "Username4", "score": "9000"}
]
```

**users.json**

```
[
{"name": "Username", "karma": "00000"},
{"name": "Username2", "karma": "00000"},
{"name": "Username3", "karma": "00000"}
]
```

Comment: So I've made these changes in my files: exporters.py => https://ghostbin.com/paste/wb3qa - settings:py => https://ghostbin.com/paste/td2qn - Reddit.py => https://ghostbin.com/paste/4yyhs | Then wrote `scrapy runspider Reddit.py` but nothing happened, Did I miss something, or Am I supposed to move these files in a Single-folder?

Comment: You need to use `-o example.json`

Comment: Got this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testing'`

Comment: That is because testing was the scrapy project name I had created. You need to update that to your project name

Answer (score 0):

The spider is yielding two items when it crawls a user page. Perhaps it would work if:

```
def parse_user(self, response):
    topics = response.meta.get('topics')

    users = {}
    users["name"] = topics["author"]
    users["karma"] = response.css('span.karma::text').extract_first()
    topics["users"] = users

    yield topics
```

You can the post-process the JSON as you need.

BTW, I don't understand why you use the plural ("topics") when dealing with single elements (a single "topic").

Comment: I aim to make it both on a different file by the plural names `topics` and `users`, That why I used the plural, Just to tell which file's list

Comment: Scrapy will produce a single stream of JSON records. It's easy to post-process that stream using tools like `jq`. If you want two types of record in the stream, add a `type` field to each to make them easy to differentiate.