# exporting data to seperate csv files in scrapy

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I have made a scrapy crawler that goes to this site `https://www.cartoon3rbi.net/cats.html`then by first rule open the link to every show, get its title by parse_title method, and on third rule open every episode's link and get its name. its working fine, i just need to know how can i make a seperate csv file for each show's episodes's names with titles in parse_title method being used as name of the csv file. Any suggestions?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class FfySpider(CrawlSpider):
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1
    }
    name = 'FFy'
    allowed_domains = ['cartoon3rbi.net']
    start_urls = ['https://www.cartoon3rbi.net/cats.html']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="pagination"]/a[last()]'), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="cartoon_cat"]'), callback='title_parse', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="cartoon_eps_name"]'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def title_parse(self, response):

        title =  response.xpath('//div[@class="sidebar_title"][1]/text()').extract()


    def parse_item(self, response):
        for el in response.xpath('//div[@id="topme"]'):
             yield {
                 'name': el.xpath('//div[@class="block_title"]/text()').extract_first()

             }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export scrapy items to different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083638/export-scrapy-items-to-different-files)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the titles stored in a list `titles` and the respective contents stored in a list `contents`, you could call the following custom function `write_to_csv(title, content)` each time to write the content to a file and save it by the name `<title>.csv`.

```py
def write_to_csv(title, content=''):
    # if no content is provided, 
    # it creates an empty csv file.
    with open(title+'.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)

for content, title in zip(contents, titles):
    write_to_csv(title, content)
```